# Error calling modules when using x = _import_("y") with dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, python-import

I'm having trouble understanding an issue with calling packages after they have been imported using the __import_ function in Python.  I'll note that using the usual `import x as y` works fine, but this is an learning exercise for me.  I am importing and then checking the version for multiple packages and to learn a little more about Python, I wanted to automate this by using a dictionary.

My dictionary looks something like this:

```
pack = {"numpy": ["np", "1.7.1"]}
```

and I then use this to load and check the modules:

```
for keys in pack.keys():
    pack[keys][0] = __import__(keys)
    print("%s version:      %6.6s (need at least %s)" %(keys, pack[keys][0].__version__, pack[keys][1]))
```

This works fine, but when I later try to call the package, it does not recognize it: `x = np.linspace(0,10,30)`
produces an error saying np isn't recognized, but this works: `x = pack[keys][0].linspace(0,10,30)`

Since this is just a way for me to learn, I'd also be interested in any solutions that change how I've approached the problem.  I went with dictionaries because I've at least heard of them, and I used the _import__ function since I was forced to either use quoted characters or numeric values in my dictionary values.  The quoted characters created problems for the `import x as y` technique.

Comment: You've imported the package, but you haven't actually assigned it to a name in the local namespace.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that's what the left hand side of `x' = __import__(x)` did.  Do you know where I would need to change my code to fix it?

Comment: But you didn't assign to a variable, you assigned to an element inside a dict.

Comment: I see that now...it was over-writing my dictionary values.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Althought it isn't a good practice, you can create variables dynamically using the builtin `locals` function.

So,

```
for module, data in pack.items():
    locals()[data[0]] = __import__(module)
    nickname = locals()[data[0]]
    print("%s version:      %6.6s (need at least %s)" %(module, nickname.__version__, pack[module][1]))
```

**Output**:

```
numpy version:      1.12.1 (need at least 1.7.1)
```

Comment: That works, thank you.  Can you help me understand what it is doing?  I'm having trouble understanding the locals() function.

Comment: locals() function returns a dict with the names of the variables in the local scope as keys and their content as values. So you can create a local variable doing `locals()['variable'] = 4`. If you `print(variable)` results 4